New movie exploring life after death, similar to Flatliners
I saw a trailer for this movie quite recently, must have been last year (2015) so I figure this movie is really fresh still. 
All I can remember from the trailer is a bunch of guys, perhaps doctors or something and they're speaking to eachother, "I want to know what life after death looks like", "but you can't", "but what if we Can"...something like that.
So the movie sure had some vibes to 1990s Flatliners.
What is the title of this movie?

Self Less, the recent movie staring Ryan Reynolds.  Some old rich guy pays to have his mind kept alive after he dies.
He is told that his new body died,  but it's really a kidnapped Ryan, who slowly emerges. A battle of souls. 
The trailer is like you described. 




It looks like "The Ghostmaker (2012)"
From IMDB:

A group of friends use an ancient coffin to experience the world as ghosts. Inspired by true events.





Was one a female? I saw a movie that had the same premises - The Lazarus Effect (2015).
Of course it had to go creepier.
